# How to embed login control in custom page when using Azure B2C login

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I am working with Azure AD B2C sample and for testing purpose I am using a slightly modified Single page app [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp). I also have an Azure B2C & a Test api (as an Azure Function) created. Test API & Single Page app are registered as proper application in the Azure B2C & the setup is working properly.

The scenario is user login in the Azure B2C, gets the token & the use the token to call Azure function. **The problem is the login page opens in a separate window with the B2C Url in the address bar. What I want is to have the login control embedded in the Single Page App.**

I went through the documentation and found one can customize the login page (in User Flow Policies/Page Layout), but it seems it will still be a separate page, which I don't want. Another idea is to have the Single Page App send the login request to my own server as AJAX request and then that server performs the login on behalf of that user and then relay back the token to the Single Page App. But it seems a lot of hassle and an unnecessary indirection, which I want to avoid as much as possible.

Following is an screenshot of the scenario:
[image: Azure B2C login scenario showing login control opens in a separate page/window]

Comment: Hi @Master Chief. Did the below answer help you?

Comment: Microsoft Azure also allow you to customize the look and feel of the sign-in page(whether for redirect or popup). You could look into those too. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, a single-page application can't embed the login experience because Azure AD B2C doesn't allow CORS or iframing, which means you are left with the following options:

1. A browser redirection
2. A browser popup
3. Posting the login credential through your own server to [a resource owner password credentials (ROPC) policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc)

Differences between browser popup and redirection are described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=javascript#choose-between-a-pop-up-or-redirect-experience

Comment: this answer is now out of date, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy for how to do this

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, the Azure B2C service doesn't allow you to do that. As per their [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs#can-my-app-open-up-azure-ad-b2c-pages-within-an-iframe):

> **Can my app open up Azure AD B2C pages within an iFrame?**
>
> No, for security reasons, Azure AD B2C pages cannot be opened within
>   an iFrame. Our service communicates with the browser to prohibit
>   iFrames. The security community in general and the OAUTH2
>   specification, recommend against using iFrames for identity
>   experiences due to the risk of click-jacking.

This is in order to keep the password as a shared secret between the user and B2C only. In this model your site doesn't have access to the password at all, it can only know the result of the authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a new feature in Azure AD B2C that's in "public preview" stage that allows you to embed iframe in your page. However there are few considerations.

> - **Embedded sign-in supports local accounts only**. Most social identity providers (for example, Google and Facebook) block their sign-in pages from being rendered in inline frames.
> - **Because Azure AD B2C session cookies** within an iframe are considered third-party cookies, certain browsers (for example Safari or Chrome in incognito mode) either block or clear these cookies, resulting in an undesirable user experience. To prevent this issue, make sure your application domain name and your Azure AD B2C domain have the same origin. To use the same origin, enable custom domains for Azure AD B2C tenant, then configure your web app with the same origin. For example, an application hosted on *https://app.contoso.com* has the same origin as Azure AD B2C running on *https://login.contoso.com*.

The feature is described **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)**