# Embed Azure AD B2C User flow ui in-line

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

The user flows in Azure AD B2C are provided as their own pages, i.e. in their own url's. Is there some ready-made javascript component that would render e.g. the login control in-line on a webpage?

In the same manner that Oktas Sign-in widget (https://developer.okta.com/live-widget/) works?

Comment: I don't think you can embed B2C's login.

Comment: @MathiasR If my answer was helpful you could mark it as answer to help others.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I don't quite feel that you really adressed my question. I was asking about embedding the login, e.g. through a javascript snippet, as in the link to Okta I provided, or some other means.

Comment: @MathiasR I understand, I have mentioned that you can customize your sign-in and sign-up policy but B2C login you have to use default template which I have mentioned on my answer. And JavaScript feature is in `Preview` .Thanks

Comment: It might not be as good as the Okta one but check **[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67653620/5790044)** on a similar question that allows you to embed iframe for login page.

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no pre-built template as per your given link. But you can use some sample template on your b2c user flow.

- You can upload your customized HTML file like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-customize-ui#create-the-customization-files).
- You can add [company branding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding) for your application login page.

In the user flow properties, you can enable JavaScript, which also enforces the use of a page contract. Then you can set the page contract version as described in the next section see the official reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-javascript-overview)  Remember JavaScript feature still in preview. See the screen shot below.

[image]

> **Note:** You could take look about what kind of [UI customization B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview) supports before you start developing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview)

If you have any more query feel free to ask here in comment. Thank you and happy coding!

Comment: Do you have any insight on the original question, i.e. if the login page can be embedded?

Comment: No you cannot embed login page but only in sign-in and sign-up page as specified on answer. Tough you can customize your landing page using company branding.